# retrieving data on second page and stop activity on first page

Tags: android, android-activity

i am trying to send some data over from first page(and stop activity) to second page,i can go to  the next page but i do not know how to retrieve information. 
also, the onClickListener is i write it myself, i heard i can set it from the properties windows, but when i click on my properties windows, it box just highlighted blue and i could not edit anything.
EDIT: I change my code to below based on the answer, it displayed distance =0.0  so i just take the dis as the text value of my texview which display the value i wanted. it display Distance:value at the second page..

```
//first page.when press this button, stop activity and go to next page
btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startButtonClicked=false;
            startDistance=false;
            String dis = (String) distance.getText();//get the value i wanted into a string
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FinishActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("dis","value");
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

this code allow me to go to the FinishActivity page
But when i am the next page, there is a problem

it just display the word Distance: value. also i have two more variable speed, duration to send, so how do i write that on the Intent? 
thanks for both of you for telling me to use Finish(); the first activity did stop. but i cannot go back. so i create another intent without data passing to just go back?

```
    //second page(FinishActivity)
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_finish);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) 
    {
        String value = extras.getString("dis");
        displayDistance=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.finishDistance);
        displayDistance.setText("Distance: " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use intent.putExtra for 2 more values and retrieve it the same way as before

Comment: it will display `Distance value`. what are you expecting other than that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startButtonClicked=false;
        startDistance=false;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FinishActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("dist","value");
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

And in Second Page You must call `Double value = extras.getDouble("dist");`

//second page(FinishActivity)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_finish);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    Double value = extras.getDouble("dist");  // change here
}
displayDistance=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.finishDistance);
displayDistance.setText("Distance: " + value); // and here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys must match

```
Double value = extras.getDouble("dist");
```

Also it is declared and initialized in the if block.

```
Double value; // declared
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_finish);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
       value = extras.getString("dist"); // keys must match
    }
    displayDistance=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.finishDistance);
    displayDistance.setText(value); // if you want the value displayed
```

To stop the activity call `finish()` in first activity when you start the second

Edit:

```
it just display the word Distance
```

It is a string that you pass and it displays the string in the second activity

```
also i have two more variable speed, duration to send, so how do i write that on the Intent?
```

Use intent and pass botth variable speed and duration and retrieve it the same way as you did before `intent.puExtra("speed","speedvalue");` and to retrieve `String speed =extras.getString("speed");`. Note the type of data that you pass string or integer or double.

```
but i cannot go back. so i create another intent without data passing to just go back?
```

If you want to go back do not call `finish()` in the first `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to store the value in EditText. Then in Main Activity:

```
String string=Edittxt.getEditableText().toString()
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FinishActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("any name",string);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // to stop
```

Second Activity:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String string = intent.getStringExtra("any name");
displayDistance.setText(string);
```